# Anyone ever get EAP-TLS working on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, wifi

I've been forever trying to get EAP-TLS working with Windows Phone 8.1 and now Windows 10 Mobile. I just can't get it to prompt for a certificate. The certificate is self signed but works fine with iOS, OS X, and Windows 8.1 & 10 tablets. I can load the certificate into the phone but the WiFi configuration always says that there are no certificates found. Using the Win 10 Mobile Certificates app I can see the cert gets loaded into the intermediate store. My guess is that it has to be in the personal store, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to generate a cert that gets loaded there. Has anybody ever gotten this to work?

Comment: I've using a Microsoft environment and CA.

Comment: Tell us more about your setup, @ongle, it's hard to help without knowing it.

Comment: What would you like to know about my setup @MikaelDúiBolinder?

Comment: What's responsible for the authentication? A Windows Server? @ongle

Comment: It is FreeRADIUS running on FreeBSD, but that doesn't matter because it doesn't get that far. The issue is getting the Windows phone to use the cert.